# How to prove that a conserved quantity does not exist in the system $\ddot{x}=-kx-c\dot{x}$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems

I would like to know how to prove that there is no conserved quantity in a system.

Let $k$ and $c$ be real numbers. Below is the ODE for the damped harmonic oscillator.

$$\ddot{x}=-kx-c\dot{x}$$

From a physics point of view, I would expect that no conserved quantities exist in this system, since energy is not conserved in it.

The definition of a conservative quantity is a non-constant function $f:\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}$ that satisfies $\frac{\mathrm{d}f(x(t),y(t))}{\mathrm{d}t}=0$ for all solutions $(x,y)$ of the following system.

$$
\begin{aligned}
\dot{x}&=y\\
\dot{y}&=-kx-cy
\end{aligned}$$

Comment: The quantity $(\dot{x}^2 + cx\dot{x} + kx^2)\exp(ct)$ is conserved. Does that count?

Comment: @eyeballfrog That function depends not only on $x$ and $\dot{x}$, but also on $t$, so it doesn't count here.

Comment: Don't forget how differentiable $f$ has to be.

Comment: @Forest There is a constant $C$ such that $\exp(ct)=\frac{C}{\dot x^2+cx\dot x+kx^2}$, so we can define the whole thing without explicitly referencing $t$. Does it count now?

Comment: @Vercassivelaunos What is the exact expression of that function? $(\dot{x}^2+cx\dot{x}+kx^2)\cdot\frac{c}{\dot{x}^2+cx\dot{x}+kx^2}$ is a constant function.

Comment: Of course it's a constant function. Every conserved quantity is a constant function!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint: If you manage to show that all flow-lines converge to the same point $(x_0,y_0)$ then any continuous function which is conserved along flow-lines must take the same value, i.e. the value at $(x_0,y_0)$.